# How do I get the text of a generated anchor tag nested in a unordered list?

Tags: jquery

I have a script that generates the alphabet and lists them horizontally. What I want to do is click on a letter in the unordered list and and populate it in the textbox.

HTML

```
<input id="letter" type="text" />
<ul id="test"></ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
        $('#test').append('<li><a href="#">' + String.fromCharCode(i) + '</a></li>');
    }
});
var li = $(this).parent();
$(this).click(function(){
var clickedLetter = li.siblings().find('a.active').text();
$("#letter").val(clickedLetter);
});
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/obadiah-williams/pen/gOGgyEp). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'this' is referring to window object, it will not give you reference of li.

```
var li = $(this).parent();
```

You don't have active class assigned to 'a'

```
var clickedLetter = li.siblings().find('a.active').text();
```

Try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    $("#test").append(
      '<li><a href="#">' + String.fromCharCode(i) + "</a></li>"
    );
  }
  
   $("#test li").on("click", function (event) {
       var clickedLetter = $(this).find('a').text();
        $("#letter").val(clickedLetter);
   });
});
```

```css
ul#test li{
  display:inline;
  margin-right:.40em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="letter" type="text" />
<ul id="test"></ul>
```

Comment: will the function not work outside the for loop?

Comment: It will definitely work outside for loop. I was testing your code so put that there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one event and use event delegation with jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const ul = $("#test");
  const input = $("#letter");
  for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    ul.append(
      '<li><a href="#">' + String.fromCharCode(i) + "</a></li>"
    );
  }
  
  ul.on("click", "a", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    input.val(this.textContent);
    // input.val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="letter" type="text" />
<ul id="test"></ul>
```